# iPad Keyboard Automatically Hiding

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard

I am having an issue with an application where whenever the user goes to login (using SSO authentication), the keyboard will display for about 5 seconds, then quickly hide. The user will then need to click on the password field again to get the keyboard to display, but then they only have a few seconds before it hides again automatically.

Has anyone run into this problem before/know of any fix?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: are you somehow calling resignFirstResponder on the textfield?

Comment: I cant really post the code since it is confidential, but the problem is only occurring sporadically so thats why I am not sure if it is a problem with the code or something else...

Comment: same problem here did you manage to solve this?